# Uninitialized value error when accessing array bytes via pointer arithmetic in C

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, pointers, printf

I'm working on a C program where I need to display the byte values of an integer array. Here's the code I'm using:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {67305985, 134678021, 202050057};
    unsigned char *byte_ptr = NULL;
    byte_ptr = (unsigned char *)arr;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); i++)
        printf("%u ", *(byte_ptr + i)); // <- 2nd function call argument is an uninitialized value

    return 0;
}

or

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {67305985, 134678021, 202050057};
    unsigned char *byte_ptr = NULL;
    byte_ptr = (unsigned char *)arr;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); i++)
    {
        unsigned char value = *(byte_ptr + i);
        if (value >= 4 && value <= 7)
            printf("%p ", (byte_ptr + i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

- %hhu or %u - doesn't change anything

In this code, I'm initializing a pointer byte_ptr to the start of the array arr. Then, in a loop, I'm using pointer arithmetic to access each byte of the array and print its value.

However, my static analyzer is giving me an error on the line with the printf call, saying that the 2nd function call argument is an uninitialized value. This is confusing to me because byte_ptr is initialized to point to arr, and I'm only accessing the bytes within the range of arr.

Can anyone help me understand why I'm getting this error and how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

I'm not sure what this static analyzer is, I'm currently working with a machine that checks the university system, and it outputs something like this:

Here are the commands:

1. cppcheck --std=c11 --enable=all --xml-version=2 --error-exitcode=42 --includes-file=/usr/include --suppress=missingIncludeSystem --suppress=variableScope --suppress=unmatchedSuppression 10.9_jak_przechowana_jest_tablica_w_pamieci.c
2. cppcheck-htmlreport --file=cppcheck_log.xml --title=abc --report-dir=cppcheck --source-dir=./ --source-encoding=utf-8
3. scan-build -o . -stats -internal-stats --force-analyze-debug-code --keep-empty --status-bugs -o ./clang_tmp -enable-checker alpha.core.CastSize -enable-checker alpha.core.CastToStruct -enable-checker alpha.core.FixedAddr -enable-checker alpha.core.IdenticalExpr -enable-checker alpha.core.PointerArithm -enable-checker alpha.core.PointerSub -enable-checker alpha.core.SizeofPtr -enable-checker alpha.deadcode.UnreachableCode -enable-checker alpha.security.ArrayBound -enable-checker alpha.security.ArrayBoundV2 -enable-checker alpha.security.ReturnPtrRange -enable-checker alpha.unix.Chroot -enable-checker alpha.unix.SimpleStream -enable-checker alpha.unix.Stream -enable-checker alpha.unix.cstring.BufferOverlap -enable-checker alpha.unix.cstring.NotNullTerminated gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -xc -D_GNU_SOURCE -c 10.9_jak_przechowana_jest_tablica_w_pamieci.c

Cppcheck: No errors/hints found; download REPORT

Clang: Errors/hints found; download REPORT

- I need to print this out using a printf pointer.

Comment: `*(byte_ptr + i)` (which is exactly the same as `byte_ptr[i]`) is a single `unsigned char`, which will be promoted to an **`int`**. But the `%u` format specifier expects an `unsigned int`. Mismatching argument type and format specifier leads to *undefined behavior*. If you want to print the integer value of the byte, use `%hhu`.

Comment: As for the static analyzer, which is it? And what is its *exact* message? Please copy-paste it (as text) into your question.

Comment: Nope ;-;
```C
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {67305985, 134678021, 202050057};
    unsigned char *byte_ptr = NULL;
    byte_ptr = (unsigned char *)arr;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); i++)
        printf("%hhu ", *(byte_ptr + i)); // <- 2nd function call argument is an uninitialized value

    return 0;
}

```

Comment: You have just changed `%u` to `%hhu`. Does that give the same error? Aside: please don't make live code updates, only more detail for clarity.

Comment: Your static analyzer id giving you false positive. They are not perfect

Comment: Perhaps the analyser saw the `%u` (that you have now removed) and mistakenly thought that the last 3 iterations were reading beyond the array bounds.

Comment: Your code edit from `%u` to `%hhu` has completely muddied the question you asked. Please post the actual code that you used. You also added another version of the code. Which ones produce the error?

Comment: `clang` as such is perfectly happy with your code, including warnings and address sanitizer. The analyzer seems to be mistaken. If you want to satisfy it anyway, you can try using a `char` array of the appropriate size either in a `union` or a separate one with the content `memcpy`-d over.

Answer (score 3):

`printf("%u ", *(byte_ptr + i)); // <- 2nd function call argument is an uninitialized value` is a static analyzer's **false positive**. [@gulpr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77737207/uninitialized-value-error-when-accessing-array-bytes-via-pointer-arithmetic-in-c/77737317#comment137047362_77737207) [@teapot418](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77737207/uninitialized-value-error-when-accessing-array-bytes-via-pointer-arithmetic-in-c/77737317#comment137047413_77737207)

Code relies on aliasing to know `byte_ptr` points to initialized data.

Roughly speaking, C can assume different types of data live in different parts of memory.  What goes on in `int` land, does not mean accessing via other type pointers sees that activity nor is even valid to cast the pointer, hence the "uninitialized value".  `void *` and characters pointers are exceptions though.

It would have been UB had `byte_ptr` been a `short *`, but is OK because `byte_ptr` points to a single byte type and is an exception to the anti-aliasing rule.

Research (anti-)aliasing rules for more details.

---

Better to use `"%hhu"` than `"%u"`.

```
// printf("%u ", *(byte_ptr + i));
printf("%hhu ", *(byte_ptr + i));
```

---

If your system is especially picky, try printing one `int` at a time.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int arr[] = {67305985, 134678021, 202050057};
  size_t n = sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0];
  for (size_t a = 0; a < n; a++) {
    union {
      int integer;
      unsigned char uc[sizeof(int)];
    } u = {arr[a]};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof u.integer; i++) {
      printf("%hhu ", u.uc[i]);
    }
  }
  printf("\n");  // Better to end output with a '\n'.
  return 0;
}
```

Ouptut

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```